# passing variables from 'ls' to 'tar' via 'xargs'

Tags: linux, ls, tar, xargs

I am trying to do something like

```
ls -t | head -n 3 | xargs -I {} tar -cf t.tar {}
```

to archive the 3 last modified files but it ends up running the tar command separately for each of the files and at the end I am left with one tar file containing the last of the 3 files (in their whatever order). I know I am not using 'xargs' correctly but searching did not help; I find examples that do not work either. Even the simpler command

```
ls | xargs -I {} tar -cf t.tar {}
```

ends up with a tar file that contains only one of the files in that directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ls -t | head -n 3 | xargs tar -cf t.tar`

Works for me.  Is there a reason you need the `-I` flag set?

Comment: It never occurred to me to try that; thank you so much! But what if I really wanted to pass them with -I? Is there a way to format it correctly that way?

Comment: If you want to use the `-I` flag then you should use something other than `{}` for the replacestring.  For example `ls -t | head -n 3 | xargs -I foo tar -cf t.tar foo`

Comment: I did, but I am getting the same result: only the last file or, equivalently, it runs the tar command separately for each item.

Comment: After further reading in the xargs man page...`-I` implies `-L 1` which effectively means run the following command for each 1 line of input which is why you're seeing the results you are.

Comment: Ah, I see; thank you so much for your help; it was bugging me for days. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/using-find-xargs-tar-create-huge-archive-cygwin-linux-unix), it's better to use `r` instead of `c`, in case `xargs` chops up the inputs, yielding a tar file containing only the last chunk. So a better solution would be:

```
rm -f t.tar 2>/dev/null  # remove tar if there
ls -t | head -n 3 | xargs tar -rf t.tar
```